# How to unlock the Extreme Events in Gran Turismo 5?

Tags: gran-turismo-5

How can I unlock the Extreme Events in Gran Turismo 5?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just reach level 20.

Comment: Should note that to drive the Extreme Series yourself you need A-Spec level 20, achieved through A-Spec racing, Special Challenges and License tests. Special Challenges (mid-teen-level) can be quite rewarding XP-wise.

Comment: I am on level 28 in A spec and B Spec, still no extreem events open up in GT5 PS3... Mine ends at Expert. Is it possible I have a different version of the game?

Comment: level 19 is the level you get the dream car competition then? If thats so then that should be right. If you are failing to have them show up try beating the world championship. Idk if that'd work but seeing as i always did that competition on every playthrough, it'd make sense that it would work, as i never had this problem